# How to include multiple transactions using API

Tags: acumatica

I have an example, to create a sales order.  I attempt to create an order with two SO lines.  But I notice some unexpected results.  The unit price and discount percentage amounts are incorrect.  I suppose my commands are not set up properly.  Please advise.

[image]

```html
 context.SetSchema(SO301000);
                List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();
                cmds.AddRange(new Command[]{
               
                //SO header
                new Value { Value = "SO", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType },
                new Value { Value = "<NEW>", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr },
                new Value { Value = "01/10/2015", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Date },
                new Value { Value = "01/12/2015", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.RequestedOn },
                new Value { Value = "09952", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.CustomerOrder }, //external customer reference nbr
                new Value { Value = "ABARTENDE", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Customer },
                new Value { Value = "NEW SALES ORDER", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Description },

                //set some shipping information
                new Value { Value = "01/21/2015", LinkedCommand = SO301000.ShippingSettingsShippingInformation.SchedShipment },
                new Value { Value = "Back Order Allowed", LinkedCommand = SO301000.ShippingSettingsShippingInformation.ShippingRule },


                //add an Acumatica Stock Item to the SO transaction
                SO301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
                new Value { Value = "MAIN", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Branch },
                new Value { Value = "D000000000", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID },
                new Value { Value = "RETAIL", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Warehouse },
                new Value { Value = "5", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Quantity },
                new Value { Value = "100", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.UnitPrice },
                //add a 3% discount percentage to the unit price of the line item
                new Value { Value = "3", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.DiscountPercent },  
                

                //add an Acumatica non-stock Item to the SO transaction
                SO301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
                new Value { Value = "MAIN", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Branch },
                new Value { Value = "ACCOMODATION", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID },
                //intentially left comment line below to create an exception
                new Value { Value = "RETAIL", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Warehouse },
                new Value { Value = "Hotel for the support team", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.LineDescription },   //override the item description that is associated to the non-stock item
                new Value { Value = "1", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Quantity },
                new Value { Value = "300", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.UnitPrice },    //its a nice hotel
               
                 SO301000.Actions.Save,
                //line below allows the autonumbering sequence of the Acumatica SO order numbers, which is set up in the SO preferences screen
                SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr});


                string orderNumber = string.Empty;

                var contentReturned = context.Submit(cmds.ToArray());
                orderNumber = contentReturned[0].OrderSummary.OrderNbr.Value;


            }
            catch (SoapException ex) { }
```

Comment: try adding commit = true in the last command of every transaction line. Eg:  new Value { Value = "3", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.DiscountPercent, Commit = true }

Answer (score 2):

Set Commit = true under UnitPrice field

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have added a multiline SO. You might see something that will help.

```
        cmds.Clear();
        // create the Sales Order header
        try
        {
            cmds.AddRange(
                new SO301000_509.Command[]
            {
                so301000.Actions.Insert,
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = "SO", LinkedCommand = so301000.OrderSummary.OrderType },
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = "='new'", LinkedCommand = so301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr },
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = dealerOrder.accountCode, LinkedCommand = so301000.OrderSummary.Customer },
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = (dealerOrder.orderDateTime), LinkedCommand = so301000.OrderSummary.Date },
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = "Hubsoft Order Nbr: " + dealerOrder.hubsoftOrderNumber, LinkedCommand = so301000.OrderSummary.Description },
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = dealerOrder.hubsoftOrderNumber, LinkedCommand = so301000.OrderSummary.CustomerRef },
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = "HS-" + dealerOrder.purchaseOrderNumber, LinkedCommand = so301000.OrderSummary.CustomerOrder },

                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = dealerOrder.notes, LinkedCommand = so301000.OrderSummary.NoteText},

                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = "true", LinkedCommand = so301000.ShippingSettingsShipToInfo.OverrideAddress },
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = shipStreet1, LinkedCommand = so301000.ShippingSettingsShipToInfo.AddressLine1 },
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = shipStreet2, LinkedCommand = so301000.ShippingSettingsShipToInfo.AddressLine2 },
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = shipCity, LinkedCommand = so301000.ShippingSettingsShipToInfo.City },
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = shipState, LinkedCommand = so301000.ShippingSettingsShipToInfo.State },
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = shipCountry, LinkedCommand = so301000.ShippingSettingsShipToInfo.Country },
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = shipPostal, LinkedCommand = so301000.ShippingSettingsShipToInfo.PostalCode },
            }
            );
            //create the sales order lines in loop
            for (var idx = 0; idx < SalesOrderLine.Length; idx++)
            {
                cmds.AddRange(
                    new SO301000_509.Command[]
                {
                    so301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
                        //simple line adding
                        so301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = SalesOrderLine[idx].inventoryCD, LinkedCommand = so301000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID },
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = SalesOrderLine[idx].UOM, LinkedCommand = so301000.DocumentDetails.UOM },
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = SalesOrderLine[idx].Qty, LinkedCommand = so301000.DocumentDetails.Quantity },
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = "MAIN", LinkedCommand = so301000.DocumentDetails.Warehouse},                        
                        new SO301000_509.Value { Value = SalesOrderLine[idx].UnitPrice, LinkedCommand = so301000.DocumentDetails.UnitPrice, Commit = true },
                }
                );
            }
            cmds.Add(so301000.Actions.Save);                                                    //save all
            cmds.Add(so301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr);                                           //return Order #

            // Submit the SalesOrder to save it
            SO301000_509.Content[] SO301000Content = context.Submit(cmds.ToArray());            //submit
            PXTrace.WriteInformation(SO301000Content[0].OrderSummary.OrderNbr.Value);
            // Retrieve the new Sales Order #
             acumaticaSONbr = SO301000Content[0].OrderSummary.OrderNbr.Value;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PXTrace.WriteError("Error adding Sales Order - " + ex.Message);
        }
        return acumaticaSONbr;
    }
```